# Why can't you define magic methods to be exactly like their builtin counterparts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making an irc bot and tons of the scripts return things that fit nicely into a `f'{label}: {value}'` format. So I made a Result class and gave it the `__bytes__` method because I've used it before and it worked fine. Or so I thought...

```
WHITE = '00'
BLACK = '01'
DARK_BLUE = '02'
DARK_GREEN = '03'
RED = '04'
DARK_RED = '05'
PURPLE = '06'
ORANGE = '07'
YELLOW = '08'
GREEN = '09'
TEAL = '10'
CYAN = '11'
BLUE = '12'
PINK = '13'
GREY = GRAY = '14'

def colorize(msg, color):
  """Add color code to message"""
  return f'{color}{msg}'

class Result:

  def __init__(self, label, value, color=RED):
    self.repr = f'{colorize(label, color)}: {value}'

  def __bytes__(self, encoding='utf-8'):
    return self.repr.encode(encoding)

def join_results(results, sep=' '):
  """Break results into a maximum of 350 bytes per line"""
  sep = sep.encode() if isinstance(sep, str) else sep
  if not isinstance(sep, bytes):
    raise TypeError('sep must be bytes or str')
  if (not isinstance(results, list)) or (not results):
    return []
  seplen = len(sep)
  x = bytes(results[0], encoding='utf-8')
  ret = []
  for result in results[1:]:
    y = bytes(result)
    msglen = len(y) + len(x)
    if (msglen + seplen) > 350:
      ret.append(x.decode())
      x = y
    else:
      x = sep.join((x, y))
  return ret + [x.decode()]
```

In the code above, calling bytes on a Result throws a type error:

```
>>> bytes(r, encoding='utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#265>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes(r, encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

There are cases though where I'd like `join_results` to also work on lists of strings. It is simple to change x in join_results to `x = bytes(str(results[0]), encoding='utf-8')` instead of `x = bytes(results[0], encoding='utf-8')` but why? Then i'll have to add __str__ to Result and waste cpu time converting any argument to x a string.

I also checked this out for other things like `__int__` whose builtin function also accepts a `base` argument for converting a string into an int. But like `__bytes__`, it also throws `TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base`. The error messages are clear so to reiterate: I'm not asking *why* it is throwing the errors. I'm asking what is the logic behind being forced to jump through hoops to make things like `__str__` or `__bytes__` or `__int__` work as the builtin functions do.

Comment: Umm, sorry but are you asking why `bytes(r, encoding='utf-8')` requires `r` to be a `str`? Maybe because encoding something else does not really make sense. Would you like `bytes` on `bytes` to be identity, despite the `encoding` argument? I guess it's a design decision. User tries to do something nonsensical, do we error them out or do we silently ignore it. Btw. you don't need to provide `__str__` if this is your problem I can post a "workaround"/solution for your problem.

Comment: @luk32 Third option(which is what PHP takes somtimes): Do something unexpected behind the scenes which will confuse the user and return the result.

Comment: @leaf I thought this is JS way. Failure is not an option. =]

Comment: I get a SyntaxError when running this: `return f'{color}{msg}'`, what were you trying to do there, format the string? I may be able to help once that's fixed.

Comment: @luk32 Nope. PHP takes the exact same approach ;-). See _[PHP: a fractal of bad design](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)_.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi it's [literal string interpolation, part of Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "like their builtin counterparts".  Doing `bytes(b'hello', encoding='utf-8')` raises an error just like the one you're encountering.  And if you call `bytes(results[0])` without an encoding argument, it works.  So your object is already working like a builtin `bytes` object.  How do you expect your object to be converted to `bytes` under a given encoding without being converted to `str` in between?  Remember that `bytes` objects do not "know" their own encoding, so there's no way for `bytes` to know that your data is already in UTF-8.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I learn something new every day..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a problem that `bytes` with `encoding` do not work as identity function.

You think that you are forced to convert your `bytes` to `str` just to reencode them, but that is not true. You just need not to try to encode bytes.

You can work around it by writing a little helper function which would extend the functionality to suit your needs:

```
coerce_to_bytes = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, bytes) else bytes(x, encoding='utf-8')
s = "foo"
b = b"bar"
print(coerce_to_bytes(s), coerce_to_bytes(b))
>>> b'foo' b'bar'
```

This is exactly what you expect. At least for bytes and strings. I guess if you need to handle all types, then logic would complicate a bit, but not that much.